# Panel de notificaciones WinForms c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día,

Estoy desarrollando un sistema el cual consta de distintos módulos: tareas, envios, libros, entre otros.

La idea en el modulo de tareas y envios, es poder notificar al usuario cuando se le ha asignado una nueva tarea, para ello, tengo un timer que consulta si hay una tarea asignada cada cierto tiempo y en base a su estado, lo cambio para evitar que siga notificando.

Ahora quiero ir más allá y poder hacer un panel de notificaciones al estilo MercadoLibre o web que mantenga un historico por cierto tiempo de las notificaciones para ese usuario pero no tengo ni idea de como comenzar, que me pueden recomendar? Estoy usando DevExpress y mi desarrollo es en WinForms.

Mi otro punto, volviendo al timer que hoy en dia hace correr mi query para saber si un usuario tiene una tarea asignada, es que no puedo saber si esa tarea cambió de estado para volver a notificar al usuario, ya que de ejecutarse a cada momento con el mismo estado, hace que siempre salga la misma notificación, por eso manejo el cambio de estado, pero como puedo hacer que notifique todos los cambios que se realizan sin duplicar las notificaciones?

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo plantearía creando una tabla TBL_TAREAS con un campo Id único e incremental y luego otro campo ID_USER, otro ESTADO, FECHA,... A parte tendría otra tabla TBL_NOTIFICACIONES con un campo Id único e incremental, otro ID_TAREA, otro DESCRIPCION, otro ESTADO, otro FECHA... Hay que relacionar los campos de ambas tablas TBL_TAREAS.Id -> TBL_NOTIFICACIONES.ID_TAREA

Esta estructura nos permite saber qué tareas tiene asociadas un Usuario, el estado de las mismas así como las notificaciones asociadas a dichas tareas y sus estados.

Cuando añado una notificación se genera un Id automático, la añado con un ID_TAREA conocido (que es la tarea sobre la que se genera la notificación) y que tiene tambien un campo ESTADO en TBL_TAREAS que si no está finalizado admite notificaciones; le pongo una descripcion a la notificación y establezco un estado (por ejemplo 1:primera notificación).

Cuando tu Listener (con tu timer) haga un barrido para ver si hay nuevas notificaciones para un usuario, mirará qué tareas tiene asociada y están activas y sobre ellas podrá leer también que hay una notificación asociada a dicha tarea y con estado 1.

Cuando hemos creado la notificación se ha añadido también el campo FECHA lo que nos permite discriminar y mostrar sólo las no leídas o las que sean recientes.

Comment: Genial! No me lo habia planteado teniendo la fecha de lectura de la notificación vs la hora actual del sistema.

Otra consulta, como puedo hacer un pequeño modulos de notificaciones donde se mezclen todas estas tareas en un solo modulo? algo al estilo MercadoLibre, que se muestra el panel de la campana en orden de notificaciones

Comment: Ya lo tienes todo. Creas tus tablas, tus querys para leer las notificaciones y también tus UPDATE para actualizar los valores de estado de una notificación y de una tarea. Por ejemplo, cuando has leído estado = 1 (primera notificación) y mostrado al usuario, haces un UPDATE para actualizar dicho campo estado=2 (ya notificada) Eso te permitirá que no muestres dos veces la misma notificación.

Comment: Si, lo que me planteaste lo entendí perfectamente. Pero tengo varios modulos, que son diversas tareas, es decir, no todas las tareas vienen de un unico modulo. Lo que me planteo, es como mezclar todas esas notificaciones, en una misma tabla o centro de notificación?

Comment: La tarea ya la tienes asociada a la notificación por su Id, ya que cada notificación está asociada a una tarea con su campo ID_TAREA. Basta que en tu tabla TBL_TAREAS definas un campo ID_TIPOTAREA. De esta forma con la misma tabla y estructura albergas distintos tipos de tareas filtrables por dicho campo sin necesidad de mayores cambios y cuyas notificaciones funcionarán de la misma forma para un tipo de tarea que para otro.